# Remove Node from XML file

Tags: python, xml

I would like to remove *CommentsCorrections* node from my xml file. I used the `ElementTree` XML API for removing the node. I don't know why my python code is not working, following are examples of python and xml.

Python:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
tree = ET.parse("pubmed_result.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for CommentsCorrections in root.findall('CommentsCorrections'):
     tree.remove(CommentsCorrections) 
tree.write("Scheduler.xml")
```

XML:

```
<CommentsCorrectionsList>
  <CommentsCorrections RefType="Cites">
    <RefSource>Clin Infect Dis. 2005 Nov 1;41(9):1254-60</RefSource>
    <PMID Version="1">16206099</PMID>
  </CommentsCorrections>
  <CommentsCorrections RefType="Cites">
    <RefSource>J Antimicrob Chemother. 1998 Jun;41 Suppl D:7-11</RefSource>
    <PMID Version="1">9688447</PMID>
  </CommentsCorrections>
  <CommentsCorrections RefType="Cites">
    <RefSource>J Antimicrob Chemother. 2008 Mar;61(3):721-8</RefSource>
    <PMID Version="1">18218645</PMID>
  </CommentsCorrections>
  <CommentsCorrections RefType="Cites">
    <RefSource>Infection. 1987;15 Suppl 5:S248-53</RefSource>
    <PMID Version="1">3325435</PMID>
  </CommentsCorrections>
  <CommentsCorrections RefType="Cites">
    <RefSource>N Engl J Med. 2005 Sep 8;353(10):988-98</RefSource>
    <PMID Version="1">16148284</PMID>
  </CommentsCorrections>
</CommentsCorrectionsList>
```

Comment: You should perform the remove on the `root`, not on the `tree`. Read the docs for good examples.

Comment: Removing all *CommentsCorrections* would render an empty root. Did you want to retain their child nodes: *RefSource* and *PMID* ?

Comment: @Parfait I don't need any child nodes, delete entire nodes , I have more another nodes, i need only delete this nodes including child

Answer (score 0):

You need to call remove method from root.

```
for CommentsCorrections in root.findall('CommentsCorrections'):
    root.remove(CommentsCorrections)
tree.write("Scheduler.xml")
```